# How to stay logged in with azure cli?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

We are using the azure cli to gather metrics for monitoring. Today the az cli failed with this error message.

> AADSTS70043: The refresh token has expired or is invalid due to
> sign-in frequency checks by conditional access. The token was issued
> on 2020-10-20T21:55:46.8597518Z and the maximum allowed lifetime for
> this request is 43200. Trace ID: ebdc2968-169d-46d2-b708-f93f8f151700
> Correlation ID: 3d2c369b-bf7a-48e3-9add-6c1ef41ae41b Timestamp:
> 2021-01-25 17:35:51Z

To get it working again I had to do `az login` and reauthenticate.

How long will the account stay logged in before having to reauthenticate again? Is there a way to keep it logged in for longer, or to configure things such that manually reauthenticating isn't necessary?

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by your company’s use of conditional access policies, not by the Azure CLI itself. You can read up on what this means [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime#user-sign-in-frequency)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to stay logged in, it's to assign a managed identity to the VM where the az cli is used.